# Optimization of a nonlinear function (spline approximation) with `Optim` gives low performance

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, spline

I have a problem in regard to using `Optim` package.

My optimization problem involves a non-linear function.

Object function and its gradient are calculated by spline generations.

Hence, I add `s` of `Spline2` package on them.

However, this process consumes lots of time, although it gives an intended solution.

Even 4 times more than its R-programming counterpart.

(I can post the R code if it is needed)

I'm wondering that julia's `Optim` package does not have good performance with theses kind of problems, like gradients having non-algebratic parts.

Here is a working example of my code.

```
using Splines2
using LinearAlgebra
using Optim
using Distributions



## basic settings (its codes are irrelevant to questions)
n=200
p=100
q=100
r=10

X = randn(n, p)
Y = randn(n, q)
B = ones(p, r) ./ p
G = ones(q, r) ./ q
Z = (X * B + Y * G)
Z_c = Z .- mean(Z, dims = 1)
Z = Z_c ./ mapslices(std, Z_c, dims = 1)
theta = convert(Array{Float64}, LinRange(-3.8, 4, 5))
knots = convert(Array{Float64}, LinRange(-7.2, 7.5, 9))
coef = (3*diff(vcat(0, theta, 0)) ./ (knots[4:end] - knots[1:end-3]))[2:end-1]

function link_approx(x_v::Array)
    local est; local der
    est = bs(x_v, knots = knots, order = 4)[:, 3:end-3] * theta
    der = bs(x_v, knots = knots, order = 3)[:, 3:end-3] * coef
    return Dict{Symbol, Array{Float64}}(:est => est, :der => der)
end


## Why it takes so long time?

@time for j in 1:r
# for update G
    function grad!(storage, gamma)
      local linkfit
      linkfit = link_approx(Y*gamma)

      output = transpose(Y) * ((X*B[:,j] + linkfit[:est] - Z[:,j]) .* linkfit[:der])./n 

      for i in 1:size(Y)[2]
        storage[i] = output[i]
      end
    end
  
    function obj(gamma)
      return norm(Z[:,j] - X* B[:,j] - link_approx(Y*gamma)[:est], 2)^2/(2*n)
    end
  
    temp = optimize(obj, grad!, G[:,j], BFGS(), Optim.Options(iterations = Int(5e1)))
    G[:,j] = Optim.minimizer(temp)

end
```

These codes spend about 5 seconds with my laptop (set 9th gen. Intel CPU i7-9750H, 16GB memory).

I think `grad!` in my code has a problem.

I should use a for-loop filling its storage to avoid errors in my knowledge.

Comment: You can read the performance tips in the Julia manual here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ In particular, avoid global variables, put your code in functions (`for j in 1:r` etc. should be _inside_ a function). Don't define functions (`grad!`, `gamma`) inside a loop, and don't let them use global variables. Use `view`s instead of slices, and return tuples, not dictionaries. Also, do not convert ranges to arrays, let `theta = LinRange(-3.8, 4, 5)`, etc.

Comment: @DNF Thank you. I have read the performance tip. I can change all points you mentioned, but I could not replace loop in `grad!`. I think the storage of it requires assigning each element (in the 100x1 vector) respectively. Otherwise, it gives an error.

Comment: I meant the loop _outside_ `grad!`. You should not define functions inside loops, it will not work correctly, unless it's an anonymous function. Move `grad!` and `obj` outside the loop, making sure that they accept all the parameters they need, like `B, X, Y, Z, n`. There should be no global variables (except perhaps some `const` values) if you want good performance.

Comment: There are also some other strange things about your code. The matrices `B`, `G` and `Z` all have rows with constant values, which means you are storing and accessing a lot of redundant information. `Z[:,j] - X* B[:,j]` could just be `Z - X * B` if you made `Z` and `B` vectors instead. Try to reduce your use of arrays in general.

Comment: @DNF many thanks! I'll try and compare its performance. I did not realize using Z[:, j] and B[:.j] instead of Z and B generates redundant calculations.

Comment: @DNF I have a question about it-"There should be no global variables (except perhaps some const values)". I understood using Global variable in a function leads lower performance. Whatif the variables are constant? Is there any different?

Comment: Yes, `const` globals can avoid the performance pitfalls, but then they must be actually constant, and not modified. Global variables are anyway undesirable, because they make code more messy and hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also consider using another implementation of `lbfgs` I tried the following, which seems faster.

```
using JSOSolvers, ManualNLPModels

@time for j in 1:r
    function obj(gamma)
      return norm(Z[:,j] - X* B[:,j] - link_approx(Y*gamma)[:est], 2)^2/(2*n)
    end

    function grad!(storage, gamma)
        local linkfit
        linkfit = link_approx(Y*gamma)
    
        output = transpose(Y) * ((X*B[:,j] + linkfit[:est] - Z[:,j]) .* linkfit[:der])./n 
    
        for i in 1:size(Y)[2]
          storage[i] = output[i]
        end
        return storage
    end
  
    nvar = size(Y)[2]
    x0 = zeros(nvar)
    nlp = NLPModel(x0, obj, grad = grad!)
    stats = lbfgs(nlp, max_eval = Int(5e1))
    G[:,j] = stats.solution

end
```

Comment: Thanks, it takes 1.6 faster than my previous codes.